# MySQL - setting foreign keys with composite pattern (mapping multiple tables to one map)

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys

I'm setting up an application database and I'm having a hard time setting up the foreign keys. The basic design involves three tables: users, clients, and contact_map. Users have Clients. Both users and clients have multiple phone and email accounts. The contact map holds those. It has UserID, UserType, Key, Value.

UserID=the id from either the client or user table. 
UserType=enum('user', 'client')
Key/value= the phone or email address key/value pair.

Is what I'm trying to do possible and if so, how do you do it?

This is what I tried, but it didn't work.

```
CREATE TABLE CONTACT_MAP
...
CONSTRAINT 'ContactMap_Users'
    FOREIGN KEY ('UserID', 'UserType' )
    REFERENCES USERS ('ID')
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT 'CONTACT_MAP_CLIENTS'
    FOREIGN KEY ('UserID', 'UserType )
    REFERENCES CLIENTS ('ID')
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Comment: Are you trying use `CONTACT_MAP` table to represent a relationship between users and clients (and is it 1:N or M:N)? Or, is the `CONTACT_MAP` actually independent of any relationships that users and clients might have?

Comment: It is independent of their relationship. It is simply to account for both users and clients to have multiple phone numbers, emails addresses, facebook, google+, twitter accounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When writing down the FOREIGN KEY constraint, the number of fields in the child table needs to match to the number of fields that you are trying to reference from the parent table. So, you can write...

```
FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES USERS (ID)
```

...or...

```
FOREIGN KEY (UserID, UserType) REFERENCES USERS (ID, UserType)
```

...but not...

```
FOREIGN KEY (UserID, UserType) REFERENCES USERS (ID)
```

You can't really employ the `UserType` to "select" the correct FOREIGN KEY. One way to circumvent the need for that is to emulate inheritance and have just one FOREIGN KEY:

[image: ER Model]

Entity-relationship term for this is "category" (see the  [ERwin Methods Guide](https://support.ca.com/cadocs/0/e002961e.pdf), section: "Subtype Relationships"). The category symbol is:

[image: Category]

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. A foreign key can only apply to a single "foreign" table.

Consider what happens if you've got a record in 'AGENTS' and in 'CLIENTS' that both reference the same record in ContactMap_Users. You've got them set to no action, but let's pretend that they're set to cascade. No, if you delete the parent record in `CLIENTS`, the DBMS will follow the foreign keys and delete the child record in contactmap_users... and now the other parent record in `ACTIONS` is dangling...

Same for an update. You update the record in `ACTIONS`, which cascades down to this maps table, and now the parent record in CLIENTS is dangling.

Comment: Sorry, agents are users (I thought it would be easier for others to relate if I changed it). I could separate them into two identical tables, but instead would rather use a column "enum('user', 'client') to distinguish the two. Sort of like inheritance or a composite pattern. Two different sets of data sharing the same table.